# CRUDing composite object using association properties / LINQ2SQL desginer

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

First of all some notes:
1. As I realize I'm asking for relatively a lot, I shall offer a (humble 50 rep) bounty ASAP, even if I'll get an answer before doing that.
2. I'm noob at this, so any direction would help.
3. I'd like only Linq2Sql designer or association properties solution, as it seems most elegant.
4. this is a follow-up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843462/how-do-you-get-values-from-three-different-tables-using-linq-to-sql) question where I got some directions, but couldn't really make it done.
5. I've really looked up this subject thoroughly, but couldn't understand how to do this.
6. I'm using ASP.NET MVC

And now the question:

I have three sql tables:
**Questions:**
ID
Body

**QuestionsAndAnswers:**
QuesionID
AnswerID

**Answers:**
ID
Body
IsCorrect

Each has a corresponding Class:

```
[Table]
public class Questions  
{  
  [Column]public int ID;  
  [Column]public string Body;  
}   

[Table]      
public class QuestionsAndAnswers   
{
  [Column]public int QuestionID;
  [Column]public int AnswerID;  
}  

[Table]
public class Answers
{
  [Column]public int AnswerID;  
  [Column]public string Body;
  [Column]public bool IsCorrect;
}
```

I also have object model class that represent a question:

```
public class Question  
{
  public string Body;  
  public List<Answer> Answers;
}
```

My question is how do I CRUD over my object model.
How is the mapping between the DB - associated classes - object model is done?

Here's what I started doing using the designer:
[image]

But I can't really say I understand how this works.
Is the object model class necessary, or should I lose it?
And how do I make this all as "automatic" as possible?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It sounds like you are coding all this by hand. Is there some reason you are not just dragging the tables from the Server Explorer into the designer?

Comment: @jarrett - When I asked the question, I didn't now anything about how to do that. Now I know a bit more and realize that defining the relationships on the tables themselves allow the drag and drop, but I still can't say I know how to complete this task. Hopefully I will after completing NerdDinner tutorial. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to purely hand code your entities and quickly and simple auto generate the database and DBContext then I would suggest you look at using the new features of Entity Framework 4.1 Code First (Magic Unicorn edition)

[Here is a good link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx) to get you started.